# Returning to an old job lost due to COVID-19

Tags: professionalism, career-development, ethics, careers, covid-19

When COVID-19 hit I had just finished my degree and was super excited to get back to work however with the lock downs and social distancing it was quite difficult to hold on to anything.

However eventually I was offered a internship leading to a job position in a organisation. I was placed with a like minded colleague who was in the same program I was but he was a little ahead in his progress.

Although the position was paying practically scraps I continued knowing that I would be offered a lucrative package in the upcoming months.

However as it happened another lockdown locked the city and I was forced to social distance at home and during this time my internship period expired. I contacted them immediately and found out that the organisation had reconsidered their program and were no longer going to continue with the program in its original way. When I asked for the job position they told me they had offered to my colleague since he had finished the program earlier and offered me to continue for the same duration he had or more.

I refused to give an answer immediately and the rest was history. I started working on freelance projects ever since but recently I found out that my colleague left the organisation to finish his degree and recently HR contacted me to just "catch up" on my progress after leaving the organisation.

Is it wise to recontact this organisation for a job because at one side a permanent position is better than freelance projects that are infrequent but on the other side the organisation refused to honor their previous commitment.

Comment: Some people here are going to start screaming "red flag" the moment they notice a broken commitment, but you should note that the COVID situation has been very disruptive and employers have operated in ways they may not usually do.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it wise to recontact this organisation for a job

Why not? What bad could come out of it? Ask away, it can't do any harm.
If you don't like their answer, you can refuse whatever offer they make later.
But not even knowing what your opportunities might be equals to shooting yourself in the foot for no reason.

Comment: This 100% — talk is cheap and you don't have to commit. It would be good to "catch up" with that former employee though to determine why they really left.

Answer (score 1):

It never hurts to know all your options.

What are they offering? Don't be afraid to negotiate.

Don't accept anything until you've seen the contract first. Make sure that every new promise made is in the contract.

If it's not in the contract, cross out the clause, initial it, and send it back to them telling them that they need to amend the contract before you're willing to accept it.

In the meantime, don't stop looking for other employers (or looking for other clients). Having options is what gives you leverage in such things.